# If a closed question is re-asked on a more appropriate site, is it okay to copy one's answer to the second instance of the question?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

[sexuality - Why do the Ten Commandments not forbid bestiality? - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/80038/why-do-the-ten-commandments-not-forbid-bestiality) was recently closed for being off-topic (I would guess for asking "why" and not asking about a specific denomination's position).

Rather than being moved, it has been reposted as a similar question: [sexuality - Does Exodus 20:14 ("thou shalt not commit adultery") include bestiality? - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53563/does-exodus-2014-thou-shalt-not-commit-adultery-include-bestiality)

I had already posted an answer to the first question before it was closed.

My question isn't necessarily about this specific question, but about the situation in general:

- Assuming it's already in a form suitable for the new site, is it appropriate to simply copy my original answer as an answer to the new question?
- If so, should I delete my answer from the original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general yes, you can copy your own answers anywhere you like. But use discretion to decide whether it truly does answer this new question.

In this specific case, I'd say you probably shouldn't - only the final paragraph really applies to the new question. But if you flesh it out substantially, and trim the rest of the answer, so that it's the larger part of the answer, then it would be okay.

There's no need to delete the original answer in either case, as long as it does answer the original question.

Comment: Right.  That's why I tried to make it clear that this instance was an example of the general case, where a question is re-asked without existing answers being moved with it.  Thanks.